# Struct Array Read Function Changing All Array Values to Most Recent Input - C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Where: ssize is the input size of the array, student is a globally declared struct, and read_stud is the function i use to read in arrays.

when printed out, s[count].first gives me the correct first name, but s[0] and all values after that are ALSO the same first name instead of the previously inputted value. It's changing the struct values to my most recent input!

```
struct student //this struct is global
{
    int number;
    char *first ;
    char *last ;
};

struct student read_stud (int number, char *first , char *last) //my read_stud function
{
    struct student s;
    s.number = number;
    s.first = first;
    s.last = last;
    return s;
}
```

This is in `int main`, where I use the function `s = calloc(ssize, sizeof (struct student));`

```
for (count = 0; count < ssize ; ++count)
{
    printf ("Enter student number, name and last name: \n");
    scanf ("%d %s %s", &number, &first, &last);
    s[count] = read_stud (number, first, last); 
}
```

A most heartfelt thanks to whoever can fix this for me!

Comment: problem in your scanf recheck it for taking char array.. no need of &

Comment: You should check that `scanf()` returned three values, so that if someone gives an entry such as '391 Paul St. John' (pronounced Paul Sinjun), you do not end up with every other student having the same number and name because `scanf()` can't find a number in `John`.  Always check read operations!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide storage for the first and last names in your `student` struct.

If you know what their max lengths are, use char arrays in the struct.

```
#define MAX_NAME_CHARS (20)

struct student //this struct is global
{
    int number;
    char first[MAX_NAME_CHARS];
    char last[MAX_NAME_CHARS];
};
```

Otherwise, malloc the strings and remember to free them later.

```
struct student read_stud (int number, char *first , char *last) //my read_stud function
{
    struct student s;
    s.number = number;
    s.first = strdup(first);
    s.last = strdup(last);
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Existing code:

```
for (count = 0; count < ssize ; ++count)
{
    printf ("Enter student number, name and last name: \n");
    scanf ("%d %s %s", &number, &first, &last);/*1*/
    s[count] = read_stud (number, first, last); 
}

struct student read_stud (int number, char *first , char *last) //my read_stud function
{
    struct student s;
    s.number = number;
    s.first = first;/*2*/
    s.last = last; /*3*/
    return s;
}
```

Because you assign the same value (first & last) and then overwriting with scanf. Try to malloc memory for first and last in your struct:

```
struct student read_stud(int number, char *first , char *last) //my read_stud function
    {
        struct student s;
        s.number = number;
        s.first = malloc(strlen(first) + 1);
        strcpy(first, s.first);
        s.last =  malloc(strlen(last) + 1); /*3*/
        strcpy(last, s.last);
        return s;
    }
```

And don't forget to free all the allocated memory.  (Error checking omitted for brevity.)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct student *read_stud(int number, char *first , char *last) // my read_stud function
{
    struct student *s;
    s = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    s->number = number;
    s->first = strdup(first);
    s->last = strdup(last);
    return s;
}
```

In the main:

```
char first[256], last[256]; /* 256 as example*/
struct student *s = calloc(ssize, sizeof (struct student *));
```

Comment: I don't see why this got a down-vote.  It is a reasonable answer, correctly ensuring that space is allocated for a copy of the values, which it the crux of the problem in the question.  We can niggle over error checking on the explicit malloc, etc.